# Xslt cant see assembly reference

Tags: c#, xslt, reference, .net-assembly

In my xslt i have a piece of C# code :

```
public string CleanForTableTags(string pContent){

        string input = String.Concat("<root>", pContent, "</root>");

    System.Xml.Linq.XDocument doc = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Parse(input, System.Xml.Linq.LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);

    var valueWithinTags = doc.Root.Element("table").ToString();
    string[] values = Regex.Matches(valueWithinTags, @"<.*?>")
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Select(o => o.Groups[0].Value)
        .ToArray();

    System.Guid d = System.Guid.NewGuid();
    string s = pContent.Replace(valueWithinTags, d.ToString());

    return s;
}
```

as u can see i use: System.Xml.Linq

in my webconfig ive got :

```
    <compilation debug="true">
        <assemblies>
            <add assembly="WindowsBase, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add assembly="System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
            <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            <add assembly="System.Drawing.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
            <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
    <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/></assemblies>
    </compilation>
```

And still i am getting :

The type or namespace name 'Linq' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Xml' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

What am i doing wrong?

I am using VS 2008. All paths to Dlls are correct, if i use same piese of code from a class it work without problems, but as soon it is used inside of xslt, im getting error

**Next problem :**

now its failing on

```
string[] values = Regex.Matches(valueWithinTags, @"<.*?>")
            .Cast<Match>()
            .Select(o => o.Groups[0].Value)
            .ToArray();



'System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Cast' and no extension method 'Cast' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What do you mean exactly by "inside of xslt"?

XSLT is just an xml file with transformations. Or are you using the `msxsl` namespace to include a piece of script using C#?

In that case you probably need to include `<msxsl:assembly name="System.Xml.Linq" />`
as well as using  `<msxsl:using namespace="System.Xml.Linq" />` inside the transformations file.

Here's an example of how to include a piece of script inside the transformation: http://docs.composite.net/FAQ/Developer?q=How+to+run+CSharp+function+in+XSLT%3F

Regarding the second part, about `Cast<>`, that is an extension method in `System.Linq.Enumerable` so adding the `System.Linq` namespace as a "using" should suffice (also make sure `System.Core` is included as an assembly as well).

Comment: Uwere right, i just forgot to add using namespace :D If u could answer 1 more question plz. i update Question in a sec

Comment: Just added the part to solve your second problem ;-). Let me know if that still causes problems.

Comment: Thank alot, that was a nut cracker, used almost 4 hrs on it! :D